# Unity2d: Object either moves too fast or too slow

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void MoveSteps(float speed, int steps)
{
        isMoving = true;
        if (GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<room>().playerNum == 1)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Debug.Log("clicked LMB");
                Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
                mousePos = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
                Vector2 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2());

                Debug.Log("COROUTINE: MoveSteps smooth steps process is called");
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter != steps)
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, 1);
                    // yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.0000001f * speed);
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        isMoving = false;
}
```

Above is my code to smoothly move my square to the mouse. But this moves too fast.

```
IEnumerator MoveSteps(float speed, int steps)
{
        isMoving = true;
        if (GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<room>().playerNum == 1)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Debug.Log("clicked LMB");
                Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
                mousePos = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
                Vector2 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2());

                Debug.Log("COROUTINE: MoveSteps smooth steps process is called");
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter != steps)
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, 1);
                    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.0000001f * speed);
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        isMoving = false;
}
```

Now it seems that there is a limit to the short-ness of the float in the WaitForSecondsRealtime. This moves slow and no matter how small, it caps at some number and then will not move faster. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `yield return null;`?  That will wait until the next frame.  Also, the last param in MoveTowards is the max distance delta.  Excerpts from docs:  `Control the speed of movement with the maxDistanceDelta parameter.` and `To make sure that object speed is independent of frame rate, multiply the maxDistanceDelta value by Time.deltaTime`

Comment: It still will not work and caps at 0.001f. Even `yield return null` will not work. Maybe I could try Lerp?

Comment: @ArdenyUser use Lerp is better way, because WaitForSecondsRealtime <-- this about your fps , but your moving speed not about fps right ? , So use Lerp is better I thought.

Comment: Ok good thanks!

Comment: I would think something along the lines of `Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, mousePos, speed * Time.deltaTime);` would work, but I typically use lerp.  You likely have a problem with your destination position, which should be a world position and not screen space position.